# calculate linear regression slope matrix (analogous to correlation matrix) - Python/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, linear-regression, correlation

Pandas has a really nice function that gives you a correlation matrix Data Frame for your data DataFrame, [pd.DataFrame.corr()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html).

The r of a correlation, however, isn't always that informative. Depending on your application the slope of the linear regression might be just as important. Is there any function that can return that for an input matrix or dataframe?

Other than iterating with [scipy.stats.linregress()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html), which would be a pain, I don't see any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slope of a regression line y=b<sub>0</sub> + b<sub>1</sub> * x can also be calculated using the correlation coefficient: b<sub>1</sub> = corr(x, y) * σ<sub>x</sub> / σ<sub>y</sub>

Using numpy's newaxis to create the σ<sub>x</sub> / σ<sub>y</sub> matrix:

```
df.corr() * (df.std().values / df.std().values[:, np.newaxis])
Out[59]: 
          A         B         C
A  1.000000 -0.686981  0.252078
B -0.473282  1.000000 -0.263359
C  0.137670 -0.208775  1.000000
```

where `df` is:

```
df
Out[60]: 
   A  B  C
0  5  6  9
1  4  4  2
2  7  3  5
3  4  3  9
4  6  5  3
5  3  8  6
6  2  8  1
7  7  2  7
8  4  1  5
9  1  6  6
```

And this is for verification:

```
res = []
for col1, col2 in itertools.product(df.columns, repeat=2):
    res.append(linregress(df[col1], df[col2]).slope)
np.array(res).reshape(3, 3)
Out[72]: 
array([[ 1.        , -0.68698061,  0.25207756],
       [-0.47328244,  1.        , -0.26335878],
       [ 0.1376702 , -0.20877458,  1.        ]])
```

Comment: I'm sorry to bug you here, but docs doesn't have comments yet. I approved an edit to your [numpy intro docs](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/numpy/revisions/1296?exampleId=6738) topics, please take a look. I agree that ipython-style output should not be in the code, and I guess the current version (with commented output) makes sense. In any case, you should probably only show outputs from the vanilla python interpreter, many people don't know ipython/jupyter and get confused by that output.